# JAAS Form Authentication always failing in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, authorization, jaas

I have developed web app based on Jboss tutorial examples. In result login page sending me to login-error page. I use DatabaseServerLoginModule. If replace to UsersRolesLoginModule then login is fine.

Google suggest me post http://community.jboss.org/message/141999#141999 but have not answer there.

Jboss log:

I think problem in  *11:37:09,128 DEBUG [[jsp]:debug]  Disabling the response for futher output*

```
11:37:08,902 DEBUG [CoyoteAdapter:debug]  Requested cookie session id is 3793E0F8FF02F043D9DCF5D98A85AFC6
11:37:08,903 DEBUG [AuthenticatorBase:debug] Security checking request GET /example2/
11:37:08,903 DEBUG [RealmBase:debug]   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[All resources]' against GET /index.jsp --> true
11:37:08,904 DEBUG [RealmBase:debug]   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[All resources]' against GET /index.jsp --> true
11:37:08,904 DEBUG [AuthenticatorBase:debug]  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
11:37:08,904 DEBUG [RealmBase:debug]   User data constraint has no restrictions
11:37:08,956 DEBUG [JNDIBasedSecurityManagement:debug] Creating SDC for domain=JaasDbRealm
11:37:08,957 DEBUG [JaasDbRealm:debug] CallbackHandler: org.jboss.security.auth.callback.JBossCallbackHandler@4437d3
11:37:08,958 DEBUG [JaasDbRealm:debug] CachePolicy set to: org.jboss.util.TimedCachePolicy@254fb0
11:37:08,959 DEBUG [JNDIBasedSecurityManagement:debug] setCachePolicy, c=org.jboss.util.TimedCachePolicy@254fb0
11:37:09,037 DEBUG [AuthenticatorBase:debug]  Calling authenticate()
11:37:09,039 DEBUG [FormAuthenticator:debug] Save request in session '81BC14FA6517824ADDE56EDAEC9EA0C6'
11:37:09,128 DEBUG [[jsp]:debug]  Disabling the response for futher output
11:37:09,134 DEBUG [AuthenticatorBase:debug]  Failed authenticate() test
11:37:12,885 DEBUG [CoyoteAdapter:debug]  Requested cookie session id is 81BC14FA6517824ADDE56EDAEC9EA0C6
11:37:12,886 DEBUG [AuthenticatorBase:debug] Security checking request POST /example2/j_security_check
11:37:12,887 DEBUG [FormAuthenticator:debug] Authenticating username 'admin'
11:37:13,035 DEBUG [[jsp]:debug]  Disabling the response for futher output
11:37:13,036 DEBUG [AuthenticatorBase:debug]  Failed authenticate() test ??/example2/j_security_check
```

My conf:

**login-config.xml**

```
 <application-policy name = "JaasDbRealm">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code = "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule"
             flag = "required">

<module-option name="dsJndiName">jdbc/MysqlDS</module-option>
                <module-option name="principalsQuery">select passwd from Users username where username=?</module-option>
                <module-option name="rolesQuery">select userRoles, 'Roles' from UserRoles where username=?</module-option>
            </login-module>
        </authentication>
    </application-policy>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/JaasDbRealm</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
            <description>Protects all resources</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="j_password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr colspan="2">
                    <td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem has been found. Fail datasource JNDI name jdbc/MysqlDS

Repaced to java:jdbc/MysqlDS and working OK.